# How to change IconButton's icon from callback function in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have simple program:

- Press timer button, it will launch a timer with duration 10ms
- Progress bar keeps increasing till 100%, then cancel timer and change the icon of IconButton to other icon, e.g Icon.timer_off

I have tried:

- Set a key for IconButton, then try to find object by a key, but not success.

How to change object's property in general? For example press button and then change progress bar color, or ending timer change button's icon or label?

This is full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _State createState() => new _State();
}

class _State extends State<MyApp>
{
  double _value = 0.0;

  void _onPressed(){
    new Timer.periodic(new Duration(milliseconds: 10), (timer) {
      setState((){
        if (_value == 1){
          timer.cancel();
          _value = 0.0;
          return;
        }
        _value += 0.01;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Test Timer'),
      ),
      body: new Container(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
          child: new Center(
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.timer), onPressed: _onPressed),
                new Container(
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                  child:  new LinearProgressIndicator(
                    value: _value,
                    valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.green),
                  ),
                ),
                new Container(
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                  child:  new CircularProgressIndicator(
                    value: _value,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold the value you want to change in State and change it with `setState`.
The exact same thing as 1 is rare, so use `>=`.

```
  IconData iconData = Icons.timer;

  void _onPressed(){
    new Timer.periodic(new Duration(milliseconds: 10), (timer) {
      setState((){
        if (_value >= 1){
          timer.cancel();
          _value = 0.0;
           iconData = Icons.timer_off;
          return;
        }
        _value += 0.01;
      });
    });
  }
```

And use the value.

```
new IconButton(icon:Icon(iconData), onPressed: _onPressed),
```

Comment: Thank you, saving iconData is the simplest way!